# Creating new table - how to set up table with two columns linking to same column in another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The application has an existing table `exchanges` and `currencies`.  such that

```
select id, name, currency_id from exchanges;

 id | name | currency_id
----+------+-------------
  1 | ASX  | 1      (Australian Stock Exchange)
  3 | LSE  | 3      (London Stock Exchange)
  4 | NYSE | 2      (New York Stock Exchange)
  2 | AMEX | 2
```

and

```
select id, name from currencies;

 id | name 
----+------
  1 | AUD     (Australian Dollar)
  2 | USD     (U.S. Dollar)
  3 | GBP     (Great Britain Pound)
```

Now I wish to allow users with a given base_currency of say AUD ( e.g `@user.currency_id == 1` ) to be able to do currency conversions. Initially I thought of a table along these lines

```
exchange_rate table:
base_currency (currency_id), target_currency (currency_id), exchange_rate
```

e.g. could have values of conversion of AUD to USD where you multiply the AUD amount by 0.8235

```
1, 2, 0.8235
```

If I try and create the table `exchange_rates` with two columns called `currency_id` the migration fails.  If I use another name for one of the two currency columns I get compile errors when I try to display the currency name e.g `@exchange_rate.base_currency.currency.name` gives an error whereas  `@exchange_rate.currency.name` gives AUD/USD/GBP.

Currently the exchange_rate table is as follows

```
table "exchange_rates", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "base_currency"
  t.integer  "currency_id"
  t.float    "exchange_rate"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Do I change the database names for exchange_rate table or how do I reference the exchange for base_currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ExchangeRate Model define association using foreign key

```
has_one :base_currency,   foreign_key: 'base_currency', class_name: 'Currency'
has_one :currency
```

now your can access both your currency and base currency like this

```
@exchange_rate.base_currency.name
@exchange_rate.currency.name
```

Comment: Secondly I am not in favor of creating another table for saving exchange rate. What you should do is to take any currency as base currency and then save rates according to selected constant  base currency. For example you chose US Dollar as base currency now in  currency table add field exchange_rate and save values w.r.t to US dollar. And If anyone want to convert from any other two currencies you use bussiness logic i.e(first convert initial currency to US dollar then to target currency)

Comment: Hi Abk.  Thanks for answers. 1- I am working on your first solution but for some reason having trouble with "@exchange_rate.currency.name"  However im my ExchangeRateModel ofhave belongs_to :currency as opposed to has_one.  2- Will mark answer as correct (but going home soon)as soon as I get display working.  3- Never though of second solution which Imay end of implementing.  Thanks - Pierre